# DataException from Dapper disappear when using MediatR

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-core, dapper, mediatr

I have a strange problem with `DataExceptions` from Dapper doesn't properagte correctly.

## Here's my setup:

```
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator;

    public CustomerController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        _mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(Get.Query query)
    {
        var result = await _mediator.Send(query);
        return Ok(result);
    }
}

public class Get
{
    public class Query : IRequest<IEnumerable<Result>>
    {
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class QueryHandler : IAsyncRequestHandler<Query, IEnumerable<Result>>
    {
        private readonly IDbConnection _dapper;

        public QueryHandler(IDbConnection dapper)
        {
            _dapper = dapper;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<Result>> Handle(Query message)
        {
            // the below throws because of incorrect type mapping
            // (yes, the connection is open)
            var customers =
                await _dapper.Connection.QueryAsync<Result>("SELECT Id, Name FROM [Customer].[Customers]");
            return customers;
        }
    }
}
```

## The result

> **Curl**
>   curl -X GET 'http://localhost:5000/api/Customer'
>   **Request URL**
>   http://localhost/api/Customer
>   **Response Body**
>   no content
>   **Response Code**
>   500

## Expected

I was expecting 500 with an error description and not *no content*.

This is the exception thrown:

[image]

---

If I change my `Handle` method to:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Result>> Handle(Query message)
{
    throw new DataException("What is going on?");
}
```

I get the expected result. A 500 with an error saying "What is going on?"

Because I have `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` enabled it looks like this.

> ```
> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>
> DataException: What is going on? 
> ...Customer.Get+QueryHandler+<Handle>d__2.MoveNext() in Get.cs, line 42
>
> Stack Query Cookies Headers 
> DataException: What is going on? 
> ...
> ```

But that's expected.

So what is going on? Why doesn't the `DataException` from Dapper work as expected?

Comment: What **do** you get? Customers? An AggregateException with the InnerException set to DataException?

Comment: I echo @J.Steen's question - but additional observation - you *probably* don't actually need `async` in your `Handle` method - the entire thing can probably be `public Task<IEnumerable<Result>> Handle(Query message) => _dapper.Connection.QueryAsync<Result>("SELECT Id, Name ....");`

Comment: @J.Steen I updated the post, with a bit more info.
@MarcGravell removing async/await makes no difference. I even tried changing to `IRequestHandler` still the same :(

Answer (score 0):

`MediatR`'s preprocessor aggreggates all exception from pipeline in `AggregateException`.

You have to expose it - for instance with `ExceptionFilterAttribute`:

```
public class MyExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(HttpActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        Exception exception = context.Exception;

        if (exception is AggregateException
            && exception.InnerException != null)
        {
            exception = exception.InnerException;
        }
        // check type and do you stuff ........
        context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage
        {
            Content = this.CreateContent(response),
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
        };
        //....
```